# Filter display gets broken in Chromium with favorite tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, new-nav

In Chromium (Version 41.0.2272.118 (64-bit), archlinux) selecting tag filter with *favorite tags* (containing 10 items) caused show/sort filters to be placed behind the tag list:

[image: bug in displaying]

Screen resolution is 1280x1024.

Comment: That looks really narrow - what's the display resolution?

Comment: @Joe added to question, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess my definition of "Really narrow" has changed drastically since my younger days... [320x200 anybody?]